# Conditional formatting based on data source

Tags: excel, formatting

I have an excel (excel 2013) workbook where, on the main sheet, large amounts of data come from different sheets depending on "If" statements. Is there a way to format the data to show from which sheet it's originating. So, for example, if the data comes from sheet 2 it becomes blue and from sheet 3 it becomes red.

Thanks

Comment: Is the data pulled via VBA or formula?

Comment: I tried conditional formatting but could not find a rule that worked for me.

Comment: The data is being pulled in via a formula. I could try something through vba but I would like to try and avoid that.